# Change Expo Generated Application Icon

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to change Expo generated iOS and Android Apps Icon, but I can't.

I have uploaded the icons to Google Play and App Store, and still it displays Expo Icon instead.

[image: Expo Icon]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Solution

Edit your app.json as below.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "My app",
    "icon": "icon.png", // Your icon path 
  }
}
```

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/#icon

## Why?

App's icon is independent with store's icon. You need to change the icon file in your project and config `app.json` in Expo project.

Comment: tested with `expo build:web` after replacing `./assets/icon.png` and it was still not changing the favicon

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa  use `expo customize:web` for favicon config.

Answer (score 1):

Open **app.json**

```
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/appicon.png", //here put your icon
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to change at both places of app.json-

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "My app",
    "icon": "icon.png", // My app icon
  }
}
```

and

```
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/appicon.png", //My app icon
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
  }
```